# Nexus not connecting to maven-central

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I am new to nexus and have installed my nexus manager on Linux box. I have added the remote proxy certificate  from the Repositories->Settings page and have also setup the proxy settings, but still I am gettin gthe status in the repositories list as `Online - Remote Connection Pending` Is there anything else I need to do to access the remote maven-central repository?

[image]

Comment: Proy / Firewall is allowed and correctly configured?

Comment: Yes, all is configured, I was using nexus 3, but I installed version `Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.12.0-01` and did the same proxy setup and its working and I can see the status to be online. Strange!

Comment: Nexus 3 is not officially released..may be this is a bug...

Comment: As per @rseddon suggestion, I made a request anyway and then the status changed automatically to online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current Nexus 3 builds don't do the automatic connection test that Nexus 2 does.  The status will change to online when the first outbound request is made to central.  Try running a build against the server, that should do it.

If it doesn't, then you have a network problem, check the logs for details.

Comment: Thanks for that, after making my first request, the status changed :-)